# Cannot use class from another namespace in ns :gen-class

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a `defrecord` called `ConstraintLookup` in `sre.plan.dsl.constraint` namespace.
I want to use its generated class in a `gen-class` method placed on the `sre.plan.compiler` namespace:

```
(ns sre.plan.compiler
  (:require
    [sre.plan.dsl.constraint :as constraint])
  (:import (sre.plan.dsl.constraint ConstraintLookup))
  (:gen-class
    :name sre.plan.Compiler
    :methods [^:static [makeConstraintLookupFromTargetsAndBounds 
                         [Iterable Iterable] ConstraintLookup]]))
```

I am AOT compiling with `nebula-clojure` plugin and Gradle. The compiler emits an error when it encounters the ns declaration:

```
> Task :sre:compileClojure
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ConstraintLookup, compiling:(sre/plan/compiler.clj:1:1)
```

Similarly when using fully qualified `sre.plan.dsl.constraint.Constraint` in the method declaration I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sre.plan.dsl.constraint.ConstraintLookup, compiling:(sre/plan/compiler.clj:1:1)
```

What is the problem here? I am lost.

UPDATE:

The referenced ns looks like this:

```
(ns sre.plan.dsl.constraint
  (:require [clojure.set :refer :all]
            [clojure.algo.generic.functor :refer :all]))

(defrecord ConstraintLookup [free bound])
```

UPDATE:

It seems to me that in gen-class you have to use fully qualified class names no matter what. However I still don't understand why doesn't the version with the fully qualified name work.

Comment: could you create a example project to reproduce this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good chance the `:gen-class` directive inside the `ns` macro cannot refer to classes generated as a side effect of `:require` in the same form. The code emitted by the `ns` macro calls `gen-class` before calling any of the `require`s. Thus the required namespaces are not yet compiled when `gen-class` is called. `gen-class` is called before any classes from `defrecord` are generated.

The behavior of `ns` can be seen [in the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5553) and also in the repl using `macroexpand`:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand '(ns sre.plan.compiler
  (:require
    [sre.plan.dsl.constraint :as constraint])
  (:import (sre.plan.dsl.constraint ConstraintLookup))
  (:gen-class
    :name sre.plan.Compiler
    :methods [^:static [makeConstraintLookupFromTargetsAndBounds 
                         [Iterable Iterable] ConstraintLookup]]))))
;; (do
;;  (clojure.core/in-ns 'sre.plan.compiler)
;;  (clojure.core/with-loading-context
;;    (clojure.core/gen-class
;;     :name
;;     "sre.plan.compiler"
;;     :impl-ns
;;     sre.plan.compiler
;;     :main
;;     true
;;     :name
;;     sre.plan.Compiler
;;     :methods
;;     [[makeConstraintLookupFromTargetsAndBounds
;;       [Iterable Iterable]
;;       ConstraintLookup]])
;;    (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
;;    (clojure.core/require '[sre.plan.dsl.constraint :as constraint])
;;    (clojure.core/import '(sre.plan.dsl.constraint ConstraintLookup)))
;;   (if
;;    (.equals 'sre.plan.compiler 'clojure.core)
;;    nil
;;    (do
;;     (clojure.core/dosync
;;      (clojure.core/commute
;;       @#'clojure.core/*loaded-libs*
;;       clojure.core/conj
;;       'sre.plan.compiler))
;;     nil)))
```

To work around the problem, we can call `gen-class` after `ns`. For example:

```
(ns sre.plan.compiler
  (:require
    [sre.plan.dsl.constraint :as constraint])
  (:import (sre.plan.dsl.constraint ConstraintLookup)))

(gen-class
 :impl-ns
 sre.plan.compiler
 :main
 true
 :name
 sre.plan.Compiler
 :methods
 [[makeConstraintLookupFromTargetsAndBounds
   [Iterable Iterable]
   sre.plan.dsl.constraint.ConstraintLookup]])
```